# Better Exception Message in Extension Method

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, async-await, extension-methods

We have the the following extension method:

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static async Task<T> ToAsync<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = string.Format("There was a problem extracting the content from the response. Status: {0}. Reason: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            var exception = new Exception(message);
            throw exception;
        }

        var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringContent);
    }
}
```

This method has serveral issues.  The one I'm curious about is the Source Error when debugging an MVC project, we get the extension code itself as the error:

```
Line 16:                 var message = string.Format("There was a problem extracting the content from the response. Status: {0}. Reason: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
Line 17:                 var exception = new Exception(message);
Line 18:                 throw exception;
```

Ideally we'd have this point at the calling method, since this is much more helpful.

The Stack Trace is even less helpful:

```
[Exception: There was a problem extracting the content from the response. Status: InternalServerError. Reason: Internal Server Error]
   Brightree.HomeHealth.Extensions.<ToAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() in c:\code\CareAnyware\Trunk\HomeHealth\HomeHealth.SDK\Extensions\HttpResponseMessageExtensions.cs:18
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Brightree.HomeHealth.<Login>d__7.MoveNext() in c:\code\CareAnyware\Trunk\HomeHealth\HomeHealth.SDK\Users.cs:44
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
   Brightree.HomeHealth.Infrastructure.<Authenticate>d__4.MoveNext() in c:\code\CareAnyware\Trunk\HomeHealth\HomeHealth.SDK\Infrastructure\HomeHealthContext.cs:235
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   Brightree.HomeHealth.Web.Controllers.<Login>d__26.MoveNext() in c:\code\CareAnyware\Trunk\HomeHealth\HomeHealth.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:66
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Is there something we could implement to make to provide more helpful information?

Comment: Stephen Cleary's Async Diagnostics might help: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncDiagnostics

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go - couple things jump out:

"There is a definite runtime impact." - OK, we can just use this in Debug mode, no big deal.

"PostSharp dependencies." - Will need to check licensing etc as this is for a commercial project.

Comment: You can include the actual response text in your exception to provide enought information to the caller for them to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding more helpful information, this could be a good candidate for [Caller Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) attributes.

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtensions
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static async Task<T> ToAsync<T>(this HttpResponseMessage response, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = null, [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLine = -1)
    {
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var message = string.Format("There was a problem extracting the content from the response. Status: {0}. Reason: {1}. Calling method is {2} in {3}:line {4}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase, callerName, callerFilePath, callerLine);
            var exception = new Exception(message);
            throw exception;
        }

        var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(stringContent);
    }
}
```